# Latex code of a particular function

Tags: tables, graphics, table-of-contents

I'm looking at the Latex code of the shape in this picture[image]

Comment: keep on being optimistic, that's a virtue in life!

Answer (score 4):

This is a start. Of course, the intervals all have the same width, something that you can easily fix if you have the data (which I don't). And no, this code does not have the shape of your picture, but produces something reminiscent of it.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-7.5,0) -- (5.5,0) (-1.5,-0.5) -- (-1.5,7);
\draw plot coordinates {(-7,0) (-6,4) (-5,0) (-4,2) (-3,0) (-2,6)
(-1,0) (0,6) (1,0) (2,4) (3,0) (4,2) (5,0)};
\foreach \X in {-7,...,5}
{\draw (\X,0) -- ++(0,-0.1) node[below]{$s_{\X}$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]